# Looking for a control that is similar to the string resource editor found in VS

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm attempting to find and use a control that is, or is similar to, the listview-like control you'll see when you add or edit string resources in VS.

I've used Spy++ to detect some information already: the Caption is "StringTable" and the Class is "WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.378734a" but that does not give me much to go on.

Is there a control available that will do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have used a datagridview to support this type of behavior with just one editable column.

Comment: In hindsight, that seems like a logical choice.